# How can I implement a class that can be saved in User Settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, settings

I have the following class -

```
[Serializable]
public class SoundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public SoundViewModel( string Name ) { this.Name = Name; }

    private FileInfo
        _RingIn = new FileInfo( "Sounds/RingIn.wav" ),
        _Correct = new FileInfo( "Sounds/Correct.wav" ),
        _Incorrect = new FileInfo( "Sounds/Incorrect.wav" ),
        _TimeOver = new FileInfo( "Sounds/TimeOver.wav" );

    public FileInfo RingIn {
        get { return this._RingIn; }
        set {
            this._RingIn = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "RingIn" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo Correct {
        get { return this._Correct; }
        set {
            this._Correct = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Correct" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo Incorrect {
        get { return this._Incorrect; }
        set {
            this._Incorrect = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Incorrect" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo TimeOver {
        get { return this._TimeOver; }
        set {
            this._TimeOver = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "TimeOver" );
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( string p ) {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( p ) );
    }
}
```

I need to save this class into the User Settings of the application and here is why (Please do not say "Why not just make a separate `FileInfo` entry in the User Settings for each File in the class?") : I need to hold 51 individual entries of this class (one by itself to behave as the Default, and 50 more; one for each player, and I am ***not*** making 204 entries into the Settings.

I did a quick search on how to make a class that can be serialized and the MSDN article I cam across said

`The easiest way to make a class serializable is to mark it with the Serializable attribute`

Clearly, this is not something which can be done the 'easy way'.

This is the code for this entry (and the respective list of these entries) that I have within the User Settings class -

XML -

```
<Setting Name="DefaultSounds" Type="EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
<Setting Name="PlayerSounds" Type="System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection&lt;EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel&gt;" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

C# -

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel DefaultSounds {
    get {
        return ((global::EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel)(this["DefaultSounds"]));
        }
    set {
        this["DefaultSounds"] = value;
    }
}

[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel> PlayerSounds {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<EQLControls.Controls.SoundViewModel>)(this["PlayerSounds"]));
    }
    set {
        this["PlayerSounds"] = value;
    }
}
```

I can provide more details if necessary.

How do I implement the SoundViewModel class such that when I call `Settings.Default.Save()`, the settings will be saved?

Also - one clue that I found is that when I tried to save, this is what I got within the User Settings file :

```
<EQLControls.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="DefaultSounds" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value />
    </setting>
    <setting name="PlayerSounds" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value />
    </setting>
</EQLControls.Properties.Settings>
```

### EDIT

It was suggested that I use the file names instead of a `FileInfo` object.
I tried this but it did not work - (I left the properties as `FileInfo` and stored their file names in the variables, as a first shot, I will next instead try to do the same with both as strings).

```
public class SoundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public SoundViewModel( string Name ) { this.Name = Name; }

    private string
        _RingIn = "Sounds/RingIn.wav",
        _Correct = "Sounds/Correct.wav",
        _Incorrect = "Sounds/Incorrect.wav",
        _TimeOver = "Sounds/TimeOver.wav";

    public FileInfo RingIn {
        get { return new FileInfo(this._RingIn ?? "Sounds/RingIn.wav"); }
        set {
            this._RingIn = value.FullName;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "RingIn" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo Correct {
        get { return new FileInfo(this._Correct ?? "Sounds/Correct.wav"); }
        set {
            this._Correct = value.FullName;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Correct" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo Incorrect {
        get { return new FileInfo(this._Incorrect ?? "Sounds/Incorrect.wav"); }
        set {
            this._Incorrect = value.FullName;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Incorrect" );
        }
    }

    public FileInfo TimeOver {
        get { return new FileInfo(this._TimeOver ?? "Sounds/TimeOver.wav"); }
        set {
            this._TimeOver = value.FullName;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "TimeOver" );
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( string p ) {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( p ) );
    }
}
```

### EDIT 2

I have removed the FileInfo properties and replaced with strings :

```
public class SoundViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public SoundViewModel( string Name ) { this.Name = Name; }

    private string
        _RingIn = "Sounds/RingIn.wav",
        _Correct = "Sounds/Correct.wav",
        _Incorrect = "Sounds/Incorrect.wav",
        _TimeOver = "Sounds/TimeOver.wav";

    public string RingIn {
        get { return this._RingIn; }
        set {
            this._RingIn = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "RingIn" );
        }
    }

    public string Correct {
        get { return this._Correct; }
        set {
            this._Correct = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Correct" );
        }
    }

    public string Incorrect {
        get { return this._Incorrect; }
        set {
            this._Incorrect = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "Incorrect" );
        }
    }

    public string TimeOver {
        get { return this._TimeOver; }
        set {
            this._TimeOver = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged( "TimeOver" );
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( string p ) {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            this.PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( p ) );
    }
}
```

Still no love, the saved user.config file is barren.

```
<EQLControls.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="PlayerSounds" serializeAs="Xml">
        <value />
    </setting>
</EQLControls.Properties.Settings>
```

Comment: FileInfo isn't serializable, so why not store just the file name?

Comment: That could work - I will try it...

Comment: Did not work - see edit.

Comment: I don't see any edits...

Comment: @RonBeyer Look again.

Comment: You are still using FileInfo objects, you need to remove them completely and just use strings. You can't serialize a FileInfo object, and serialization works on properties.

Comment: @RonBeyer : See edit 2 : Still no love.

Comment: Please show the entire class (including the backing fields) and how you are saving it to the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoundViewModel` needs a parameterless constructor for deserialization.  Only public properties will be serialized.  You can skip properties using `[XmlIgnore]`.

You also can't save generic types in user settings (`Observable<T>` in your case).  There's an easy work-around though and I often do this with dictionaries.

```
[Serializable]
public class MySerializableCollection : List<SoundViewModel>{}
```

Comment: Thank you good sir - I did not even need to implement a serializable collection; it was the parametered constructor that was making it fail.